# Ruby: Keep console open after script execution

Tags: ruby, console

I wrote a Ruby script like the following example. The basic functionality is the same:

```
# get input from the user
input = gets.chomp
# do awesome stuf with this input and print the response
puts do_awesome_stuff(input)
```

The problem is when I run the script it prints the solution I want, but the console window closes right after. I want the console to keep open.
I'm currently on windows, but the solution should be working on every system.

One way is to run the ruby script with a .bat file and pause it, like so:

```
ruby script.rb
PAUSE
```

I hope there is a way without the additional .bat file. Does Ruby has a function like PASUE integrated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you double click the ruby script file.

Instead issue the following command in `cmd` shell.

```
ruby filename.rb
```

If you don't want that, you can add `gets` to the end of the script.

```
# get input from the user
input = gets.chomp
# do awesome stuf with this input and print the response
puts do_awesome_stuff(input)
gets # <----
```

But this is not recommended because .. if you run the command in cmd shell or terminal you should type extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> to return to the shell.

Comment: I like the solution with `gets` at the end. I will add a sentence like "Exit the script with ENTER". Then the user knows what he has to do.

Comment: @PascalGläser, `gets` solution does not work if there's call to `exit` in the middle. Also does not work if a exception is raised; You will not see error traceback.

Comment: @PascalGläser, Normally other command line programs does not use wait for user to enter before terminate. This will make hard to combine your program with other command line program. (Think about shell features like redirection, pipe, ...)

Comment: I had the same problem. This is actually a duplicate of one of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-r` options of irb.

irb -r ./filename.rb

Comment: And please remember that local variables defined in the script/library are not available in the console afterwards.