# Ruby file won't open

Tags: ruby, windows, atom-editor

I've written two Ruby scripts in a text editor called Atom. When I try to open these files, a black command box pops up for a second and then immediately closes. Does anyone know why this happens? Is there something wrong with the Ruby files or with my Ruby installation (Ruby 2.4 4-1) on Windows?

Comment: Define "open". Do you want to load them in the editor or run them? What do you do to "open" them that resulted in black command box? (presumably double-click the file?) Do you mean you want to run the file but the window in which it was running disappears before you can inspect it? (possible duplicate [Ruby: Keep console open after script execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215337/ruby-keep-console-open-after-script-execution))

Comment: You probably ran the program in the console instead of opening it in the editor. Nothing wrong with the installation. The way you opened the file is wrong.

Comment: From what you describe, I see that the files do indeed "open".

Comment: Maybe what you can do is, open the Command prompt and then `cd` to your relevant directory and use `ruby <filename>` then you can check the output of the scripts

Comment: @Amadan I meant run. I did double click the file. was able to execute it in the cmd prompt.

Comment: @sawa you're right! opening through cmd worked.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows is probably configured to run Ruby files in the terminal (command window), so when you run (not open) those files, Windows opens a terminal to run the program, runs it, and then closes the terminal.

I suggest putting a `sleep` or a `gets` command at the end of your Ruby program so that your script will sit there for a while before the terminal disappears. Then you will be able to inspect the output.

Examples:

```
sleep 60  # sleeps 60 seconds, then the program will proceed (exit in your case)
```

or:

```
$stdin.gets  # will wait for you to hit [Enter] before proceeding
```